# Play sound based on UIImageVIew named image not working

Tags: swift, xcode, uiimageview

I developed a flashcard app and i have a UIImageView along with gesture clicks to change the picture and a button to play a sound based on the image.

Here is what's happening, i cycle thru all of the images using a number:

```
        // if the tapped view is a UIImageView then set it to imageview
        if (gesture.view as? UIImageView) != nil {
            if segControl.selectedSegmentIndex == 0 && segControl2.selectedSegmentIndex == 0 {
                imageView.image = UIImage(named: "card2")
                imageView.image = UIImage(named: "card\(number)")
                number = number % 26 + 1
            }
            else if segControl.selectedSegmentIndex == 0 && segControl2.selectedSegmentIndex == 1 {
                imageView.image = UIImage(named: "upper2")
                imageView.image = UIImage(named: "upper\(number)")
                number = number % 26 + 1
            }
            else if segControl.selectedSegmentIndex == 0 && segControl2.selectedSegmentIndex == 2 {
                imageView.image = UIImage(named: "num2")
                imageView.image = UIImage(named: "num\(number)")
                number = number % 10 + 1
            }
}
```

I then have a button that should play a sound based on the image being displayed in the imageview:

```
        if imageView.image ==  UIImage(named: "card1") {
            do {
                audioPlayer = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: URL(fileURLWithPath: aSound))
                audioPlayer.play()
            } catch {
                print("Couldn't load sound file")
            }
        }
        else if imageView.image !=  UIImage(named: "card2") {
            do {
                audioPlayer = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: URL(fileURLWithPath: bSound))
                audioPlayer.play()
            } catch {
                print("Couldn't load sound file")
            }
        }
        else if imageView.image !=  UIImage(named: "card3") {
            do {
                audioPlayer = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: URL(fileURLWithPath: cSound))
                audioPlayer.play()
            } catch {
                print("Couldn't load sound file")
            }
        }
}
```

I have set all the variables for the sound and added them as references to my xcode project:

```
var audioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer() 
let aSound = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "aSound.m4a", ofType:nil)!
let bSound = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "bSound.m4a", ofType:nil)!
let cSound = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "cSound.m4a", ofType:nil)!
```

The problem is when i press the sound button, it plays the same sound every time, it's like it never reads thru my if statement.

Comment: Does it always play bSound?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that when you try to compare images in this way

```
if imageView.image ==  UIImage(named: "card1") {
            ...
        }
```

You are actually trying to compare two different Objects which have different references.

In order to achieve your desired behaviour, you can adopt two different solution.

**The first one** is using the `tag` property of the view:

```
if segControl.selectedSegmentIndex == 0 && segControl2.selectedSegmentIndex == 0 {
                imageView.image = UIImage(named: "card2")
                imageView.image = UIImage(named: "card\(number)")
// HERE YOU CAN ADD A TAG
                imageView.tag = 1 //for example, it has to be Int
                number = number % 26 + 1
            }
```

So you compare `tag` in this way:

```
if imageView.tag ==  1 {
            do {
                audioPlayer = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: URL(fileURLWithPath: aSound))
                audioPlayer.play()
            } catch {
                print("Couldn't load sound file")
            }
        }
```

and so on.

**The second one** is to use `isEqual`, which should compare `hash` value of the Objects:

```
if imageView.image.isEqual(UIImage(named: "")){
            ...
        }
```